# Job application and Applicant tracking website

Tags: c#, oracle, ms-access

I see a lot of ATS is available online for any company who wants to implement ATS for a nominal cost. I also see a few available as opensource. 
I work in a small firm and am I come from non IT background. With my own interests have tried my hands on with some Java and C# lately.I enjoy learning programming and want to learn more. I want to design and develop an ATS for the company.We don't have one and I think it will be a great experience for me. I tried google and I found a very relevant link on same system in MS Access tutorial from MSDN Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg621254

At the end they say to publish on Share point.(optional) I have no clue about Sharepoint.
I wanted to know if I use any other Database instead of MS Access. In Oracle, they have forms and reports which is mainly used. Is there anything similar on MS Access so that I can have the Cost to hire employee calculator available? Any suggestions or ideas in general also will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance,
newbee

Comment: Please please please don't use MS Access for anything..... ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the good ol' days of where to begin.  Well, here is what I can suggest and spend a weekend watching the video tutorials just becoming familiar with what you can do.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Next is viewing others code.

**Nerd Dinner**

http://nerddinner.com/ (little more on the advance side)
http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

**Patterns** : don't just start throwing darts at a wall to see what sticks.

http://www.dofactory.com ($$, might find something similar but I've seen this and it's pretty nice for the newbee).

Read, read, read (google.com, asp.net) and watch, watch, watch (asp.net, youtube.com)!

Have fun.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! That's helpful.